# hardcoding UIView size in iPad2, working on iPad mini

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiview

I inherited an app in which there are some global variables, one of which is ViewsSize which is 666 ( an evil programmer wrote this ).
now I assume this will not work once deployed on an iPad mini? anyone has a better idea of sizing the views in a relative mode?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad Mini has the exact same resolution as the iPad 2 and is even treated the same as far as views are concerned. So while this is bad practice it will not break on the iPad Mini at all. So you can rest easy for this inherited app, just don't copy it!

Check out the docs for `UIView.autoresizingMask` as far as relative sizing for future reference.